# Play store publishing ( free app with mandatory in app products)

Tags: google-play

I am planning to publish a new app on store. The app will be free, but you will not be able to use the app unless you purchase an in app product.

You will not have to pay to download the app, but you will have to pay use it, because without a purchased product, you can not use the app.

Will google accept my app? I couldn't find any answer for this, neither the support from google gave me a clear answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your use case is certainly unusual.

While it is possible that the app is allowed on the google store, I can almost guarantee that if someone reports your app, it might get removed under the [Minimum Functionality](https://play.google.com/about/spam-min-functionality/min-functionality/broken/) section.

It will depend on what the description of your app says because as you should have guessed it should describe the base functionality of your app if it has in-app purchase or summarize the all features the app has to offer in case it is free.

As long as you mention in the description of the app that the user will have to purchase a product to use your application, you should be good to go.